# Any ideas on the list with fit/wrap width on item in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement next UI element:

[image]

- Unknown size list of strings
- Any item should be wrap content.
- If an item is not fitted to row, he will be in the next row.
- All list/grid is centered

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `FlowRow` from [accompanist-flowlayout](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/) to implement this. It renders its children horizontally (like `Row`) but also wraps them by moving to the new line if they don't fit in the existing line. It also allows to configure horizontal and vertical spacing between items.

To nicely handle very long strings (that will not fit into single line themselves) you can set `overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis` and `maxLines = 1` on `Text`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HashTagList(hashTags: List<String>) {
    FlowRow(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center,
        mainAxisSize = SizeMode.Expand,
        crossAxisSpacing = 12.dp,
        mainAxisSpacing = 8.dp
    ) {
        hashTags.forEach { hashTag ->
            Text(
                text = hashTag,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = colorForHashTag(hashTag),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(8.dp),
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: FlowRow and FlowColumn are now deprecated and you should use a custom Layout instead see here https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1521704

Comment: Any idea how you could animate add/removal of items in this group?

Answer (score 30):

**Update:** For a ready to use solution take a look at [Jetpack Compose Flow Layouts](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/) from [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/) library. For a custom solution see the answer below.

---

Since Compose version [1.0.0-alpha10](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.0.0-alpha10) FlowRow and FlowColumn are deprecated. I hope there will be some build-in solution in the future, but now you can use a custom layout as suggested by [the deprecation note](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1521704). Here's an example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TagRow(tags: Collection<String>) {
    SimpleFlowRow(
        verticalGap = 8.dp,
        horizontalGap = 8.dp,
        alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        for (tag in tags) {
            Text(
                text = "#$tag",
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                    .padding(4.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SimpleFlowRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    alignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    verticalGap: Dp = 0.dp,
    horizontalGap: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = Layout(content, modifier) { measurables, constraints ->
    val hGapPx = horizontalGap.roundToPx()
    val vGapPx = verticalGap.roundToPx()

    val rows = mutableListOf<MeasuredRow>()
    val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(minWidth = 0)

    for (measurable in measurables) {
        val lastRow = rows.lastOrNull()
        val placeable = measurable.measure(itemConstraints)

        if (lastRow != null && lastRow.width + hGapPx + placeable.width <= constraints.maxWidth) {
            lastRow.items.add(placeable)
            lastRow.width += hGapPx + placeable.width
            lastRow.height = max(lastRow.height, placeable.height)
        } else {
            val nextRow = MeasuredRow(
                items = mutableListOf(placeable),
                width = placeable.width,
                height = placeable.height
            )

            rows.add(nextRow)
        }
    }

    val width = rows.maxOfOrNull { row -> row.width } ?: 0
    val height = rows.sumBy { row -> row.height } + max(vGapPx.times(rows.size - 1), 0)

    val coercedWidth = width.coerceIn(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth)
    val coercedHeight = height.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)

    layout(coercedWidth, coercedHeight) {
        var y = 0

        for (row in rows) {
            var x = when(alignment) {
                Alignment.Start -> 0
                Alignment.CenterHorizontally -> (coercedWidth - row.width) / 2
                Alignment.End -> coercedWidth - row.width

                else -> throw Exception("unsupported alignment")
            }

            for (item in row.items) {
                item.place(x, y)
                x += item.width + hGapPx
            }

            y += row.height + vGapPx
        }
    }
}

private data class MeasuredRow(
    val items: MutableList<Placeable>,
    var width: Int,
    var height: Int
)
```

and the result:
[image]

You can find the full sample code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/icesmith/android-samples/tree/master/SimpleComposeFlowRow).

Comment: This looks great but I noticed that all the items are loading at the same time. This can be an issue if you have 1k+ items with images. Is there a way to lazy load the items?

Answer (score 5):

Flow layouts in accompanist are what you're looking for

You can find the documentation here: https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/

Specifically, the `FlowRow` will allow you to achieve what you want in your example

Comment: FlowRow doesn't align the items vertically, for example Alignment.CenterVertically

Comment: I think I just understood what "cross" means :D

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an implementation also accepting `Alignment.Vertical` to control alignment of items with smaller height, here is a modified version of Valeriy's answer:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FlowRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    alignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.Start,
    verticalAlignment: Alignment.Vertical = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    verticalGap: Dp = 0.dp,
    horizontalGap: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) = Layout(content, modifier) { measurables, constraints ->
    val hGapPx = horizontalGap.roundToPx()
    val vGapPx = verticalGap.roundToPx()

    val rows = mutableListOf<MeasuredRow>()
    val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(minWidth = 0)

    for (measurable in measurables) {
        val lastRow = rows.lastOrNull()
        val placeable = measurable.measure(itemConstraints)

        if (lastRow != null && lastRow.width + hGapPx + placeable.width <= constraints.maxWidth) {
            lastRow.items.add(placeable)
            lastRow.width += hGapPx + placeable.width
            lastRow.height = max(lastRow.height, placeable.height)
        } else {
            val nextRow = MeasuredRow(
                items = mutableListOf(placeable),
                width = placeable.width,
                height = placeable.height
            )

            rows.add(nextRow)
        }
    }

    val width = rows.maxOfOrNull { row -> row.width } ?: 0
    val height = rows.sumBy { row -> row.height } + max(vGapPx.times(rows.size - 1), 0)

    val coercedWidth = width.coerceIn(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth)
    val coercedHeight = height.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)

    layout(coercedWidth, coercedHeight) {
        var y = 0

        for (row in rows) {
            var x = when(alignment) {
                Alignment.Start -> 0
                Alignment.CenterHorizontally -> (coercedWidth - row.width) / 2
                Alignment.End -> coercedWidth - row.width

                else -> throw Exception("unsupported alignment")
            }

            for (item in row.items) {
                var localY = 0
                if (item.height < row.height) {
                    localY = when (verticalAlignment) {
                        Alignment.Start -> y
                        Alignment.CenterVertically -> y + ((row.height + vGapPx) / 2 - item.height / 2)
                        Alignment.End -> y + row.height
                        else -> throw Exception("unsupported alignment")
                    }
                } else localY = y
                item.place(x, localY)
                x += item.width + hGapPx
            }

            y += row.height + vGapPx
        }
    }
}

private data class MeasuredRow(
    val items: MutableList<Placeable>,
    var width: Int,
    var height: Int
)
```

Comment: Isn't working anymore, the smaller items are at the bottom when I've set `Alignment.CenterVertically`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **LazyVerticalGrid** and use grid cells to choose how to display the children items. more on https://alexzh.com/jetpack-compose-building-grids/ .

```
val data = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")

LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(3),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
) {
    items(data) { item ->
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray
        ) {
            Text(
                text = item,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zus6Z.png)

this is an experimental feature but it works fine and be careful with imports for items.

Comment: This doesn't suite the user needs since it only allows for fixed size. If you use Adaptive size it gets better but doesn't expand so well