# Wrap Row components

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to figure out how to figure out how to wrap my components in Jetpack Compose for narrow screens, e.g. Samsung fold.

For example:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
    Row(
          horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
          verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
       Image(...)
       Spacer(...)
       Image(...)
       Spacer(...)
       SomeBadgeWithText(...)
    }
}
```

On the narrow Samsung device, the last Badge gets squashed and text is cut off. I want it to just wrap to the next line. Is that possible?

Comment: So you're a failed Unit Test?

Comment: You can use `FlowRow` from Accompanist like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022452/any-ideas-on-the-list-with-fit-wrap-width-on-item-in-jetpack-compose/61024679#61024679

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Wrapping content like you want is not a native compose feature. However Accompanist, a set of compose libraries developed by Google, offers [Flow Layout](https://google.github.io/accompanist/flowlayout/) which should suit your use-case.